# Recorded video won't show on viewVideo

Tags: java, android

I just need help on my codes, I'm using Android Studio. Everything is working fine but the recorded video won't show in viewVideo on my layout.

Here's the code:

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    VideoView resultvideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button click = (Button)findViewById(R.id.videorec);
        resultvideo = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }

    public void dispatchTakeVideoIntent(View v) {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Uri videoUri = data.getData();
        resultvideo.setVideoURI(videoUri);
       // start call missing  
      resultvideo.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. @Sush